# Trying to build JSIL gives 47 errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, jsil

I am trying to build the JSIL project. I already have a XNA game which I want to convert to use in a webbrowser via JSIL.

I've followed up all the instructions on the JSIL wiki. Yet it gives me 47 errors when I try to build the project. I can't find a way to solve this, simply because I have no idea what causes this.

There's little known on the internet about this JSIL problem, so I hope you could help me.

For the record: I have updated all files via git and such.

These are some of the errors:

[image: Errors JSIL]

Comment: Can you post an image of that a bit larger? Very hard to see those errors. Or copy some of the text for us.

Comment: I am sorry. The image itself has a readable size, but Stackoverflow makes it small. The image is in this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WXR2X.png

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded all the external references? For example, there should be a *Upstream\JSIL.ExpressionInterpreter* folder. Are there files there?

Comment: Yes, I do have a folder with these files (for example the JSIL.ExpressionInterpreter.csproj file).

Comment: The error messages indicate that the 'JSIL' assembly (the core code translator) did not compile successfuly. The 'Compiler' assembly is the command-line executable that depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Visual Studio 2013: the JSIL_NoXNA.sln compiles like a charm.

What you can do:

- open the JSIL_NoXNA.sln in Visual Studio
- check that all the projects open correctly (they should have the standard icon, not the grayed out one
- begin building the projects one by one, manually, in the build order (right click on a project, *Build*)

The build order is:

- Mono.Cecil
- ICSharpCode.NRefactory
- Meta
- ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp
- ICSharpCode.Decompiler
- Mono.Cecil.Pdb
- Mono.Cecil.Mdb
- Proxies.4.0
- JSIL
- Compiler
- Tests
- SimpleTests
- Try
- Proxies.Bcl
- JSIL.DeadCodeAnalyzer
- JSIL.ExpressionInterpreter

You can see it with right click on the solution, *Project Build Order..*. The first project that you can't compile is the culprit. Then first check that all its *References* are "ok" (without the yellow exclamation mark)

Comment: The thing is that I DO want to convert XNA games with JSIL, can I still use this solution instead of the primary JSIL.sln?

Comment: @user2014780 Yes... Build the remaining XNA things at the end.

Comment: When trying to build the Try project I get this error: Source file 'OAuth.cs' could not be found \JSIL\Try\CSC Try. When I take a look at the source GIT of JSIL in the folder Try I cannot find this CS class either. Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: @user2014780 You can remove it. It isn't referenced. The Try should be an online snippet compiler, so nothing really necessary. But if you arrived there, then you have successfully compiled the *Compiler*! Be happy! :-)

Comment: Haha I almost got it to work! It seems like compiling works, but running the project isn't. The command promp gives me the following output: http://puu.sh/hEw4N/c964d64fce.png

Comment: @KatelynGadd Have you looked at the screenshot? You should look at it for five minutes, read it and think. It is working as it should.